# How do you prevent flash[:notice] from being rendered twice when redirecting from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple method in the ApplicationController that, when called, may set a 'flash[:notice]' then redirect to the root_url.

The problem is that even though that method is only called once, the root URL renders that flash[:notice] TWICE.

Here's a the method (which is a before_filter used in other controllers, and is defined in the ApplicationController) :

```
def authenticate
  if params[:id].try(:size) == 40
    company = Company.find_by_hash_identifier(params[:id])
    if company
      session[:editable_companies] ||= []
      session[:editable_companies] << company.id
      session[:editable_companies].compact!.uniq!
    end
  end
  unless session[:editable_companies].try('&', [company.try(:id), params[:id]])
    flash[:notice]= "You are not permitted to edit this company.<br />Please check the URL from the email we sent you, and try again."
    flash.keep[:notice]
    redirect_to root_url and return
  end
end
```

In the root_url view, I get two flashes like so:

You are not permitted to edit this company.You are not permitted to edit this company.

Comment: This looks straighforward, just use logging.

Comment: Since the question is no longer relevant, could you guys help me close it?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `flash.keep(:notice)` line.

Comment: No dice :-/ I've added the original method just to be sure I didn't miss anything in translation.

Comment: Sorry, I gotta vote down since that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yup, I know I don't need it, but that doesn't solve the problem...kinda sticky...the answer improved the code, but didn't solve the problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't (at least shouldn't) need to call `flash.keep(:notice)` to store the flash across a redirect. A value in the flash hash only gets auto-deleted on a `render`.

Comment: That's what I thought...but removing it doesn't solve the problem either :-/

Answer (score -4):

Turns out it was a problem in the view. :-(

I actually had flash[:notice] twice.

Comment: What's up with the down votes? I tried to delete the question, but there were already too many answers...

Comment: Maybe because you are giving downvotes to people who are trying to help you?

Comment: Wellp, I think I've learned my lesson. Sorry for the downvote Topley!